# Como tirar parâmetro de dentro do popup?

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho uma tela onde eu seto as paginas, e quando eu clicava na pagina abre um pop up onde eu posso digitar o valor das paginas ao invés de ir passando.(pq no caso tenho 60)

a página nada mais é do que o ID dos meus valores no banco de dados, e eu só escrevo o que eu li no ID.

quando eu executo o código ele da erro nessa linha

```
valor = etpage.getText().toString();
```

onde valor é uma variável de escopo global, do tipo String, e o campo editavel que recebe só aceita número.

o código que gera o pop up

```
    @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tv2);

    button.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    p.x = location[0];
    p.y = location[1];
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
    int popupWidth = 300;
    int popupHeight = 400;
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, viewGroup);
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
    popup.setContentView(layout);
    popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
    popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
    popup.setFocusable(true);

    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popup.showAtLocation(layout, 
            Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 1, 1 );
    Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonir);
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            valor = etpage.getText().toString();
            popup.dismiss();


        }
    });

}
```

}[image: tela debug]

tela error : unknown error: Java.Lang.NullPointerException

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
SQLiteDatabase Banco = null;
Cursor cursor;
ToggleButton bt01,bt02,bt03,bt04,bt05,bt06,bt07,
bt08,bt09,bt10,bt11,bt12,bt13,bt14,bt15;
Button btnext,btprevious, pageview,btdescricao, botaopage;
EditText etpage,etpage2;
int page=1;
String valor = "1";
int progress;
private Point p = new Point();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("main", "Executou o onCreate();");
    abrebanco();
iniciaobjetos();
    Intent ipage = getIntent();
    page = ipage.getIntExtra("pagina2", 1);
    if (page<10)
        pageview.setText("0"+String.valueOf(page));
    else pageview.setText(String.valueOf(page));
    buscardados();
    setacursor(page);
    escrevebotao();

    btprevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (page>1)
                page--;
            else
                page=60;
            setacursor(page);
            escrevebotao();
            if (page<10)
                pageview.setText("0"+String.valueOf(page));
            else pageview.setText(String.valueOf(page));
        }

    });
    btprevious.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {



            if (page>1)
                page--;
            else
                page=60;
            setacursor(page);
            escrevebotao();
            if (page<10)
                pageview.setText("0"+String.valueOf(page));
            else pageview.setText(String.valueOf(page));

            return false;


        }
    });



    btnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (page<60)
                page++;
            else
                page=1;
            setacursor(page);
            escrevebotao();
            if (page<10)
                pageview.setText("0"+String.valueOf(page));
            else pageview.setText(String.valueOf(page));
        }

    });
    botaopage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (p != null)
                showPopup(MainActivity.this, p);
                page = Integer.valueOf(valor);
                if (page>60)
                    page=60;
                if (page<0)
                    page=0;
                if (page<10)
                    pageview.setText("0"+String.valueOf(page));
                else pageview.setText(String.valueOf(page));
        }


    });




}


public void setacursor(Integer pagina){
    cursor.moveToPosition(pagina-1);

}


private void escrevebotao() {
    btdescricao.setText(retornadado("bt"));
    bt01.setTextOff("01 \n" + retornadado("bt01"));
    bt01.setText("01 \n" + retornadado("bt01"));
    bt01.setTextOn("01\n" + retornadado("bt01"));
    bt02.setTextOff("02 \n" + retornadado("bt02"));
    bt02.setText("02 \n" + retornadado("bt02"));
    bt02.setTextOn("02 \n" + retornadado("bt02"));
    bt03.setTextOff("03 \n" + retornadado("bt03"));
    bt03.setText("03 \n" + retornadado("bt03"));
    bt03.setTextOn("03 \n" + retornadado("bt03"));
    bt04.setTextOff("04 \n" + retornadado("bt04"));
    bt04.setText("04 \n" + retornadado("bt04"));
    bt04.setTextOn("04 \n" + retornadado("bt04"));
    bt05.setTextOff("05 \n" + retornadado("bt05"));
    bt05.setText("05 \n" + retornadado("bt05"));
    bt05.setTextOn("05 \n" + retornadado("bt05"));
    bt06.setTextOff("06 \n" + retornadado("bt06"));
    bt06.setText("06 \n" + retornadado("bt06"));
    bt06.setTextOn("06 \n" + retornadado("bt06"));
    bt07.setTextOff("07 \n" + retornadado("bt07"));
    bt07.setText("07 \n" + retornadado("bt07"));
    bt07.setTextOn("07 \n" + retornadado("bt07"));
    bt08.setTextOff("08 \n" + retornadado("bt08"));
    bt08.setText("08 \n" + retornadado("bt08"));
    bt08.setTextOn("08 \n" + retornadado("bt08"));
    bt09.setTextOff("09 \n" + retornadado("bt09"));
    bt09.setText("09 \n" + retornadado("bt09"));
    bt09.setTextOn("09 \n" + retornadado("bt09"));
    bt10.setTextOff("10 \n" + retornadado("bt10"));
    bt10.setText("10 \n" + retornadado("bt10"));
    bt10.setTextOn("10 \n" + retornadado("bt10"));
    bt11.setTextOff("11 \n" + retornadado("bt11"));
    bt11.setText("11 \n" + retornadado("bt11"));
    bt11.setTextOn("11 \n" + retornadado("bt11"));
    bt12.setTextOff("12 \n" + retornadado("bt12"));
    bt12.setText("12 \n" + retornadado("bt12"));
    bt12.setTextOn("12 \n" + retornadado("bt12"));
    bt13.setTextOff("13 \n" + retornadado("bt13"));
    bt13.setText("13 \n" + retornadado("bt13"));
    bt13.setTextOn("13 \n" + retornadado("bt13"));
    bt14.setTextOff("14 \n" + retornadado("bt14"));
    bt14.setText("14 \n" + retornadado("bt14"));
    bt14.setTextOn("14 \n" + retornadado("bt14"));
    bt15.setTextOff("15 \n" + retornadado("bt15"));
    bt15.setText("15 \n" + retornadado("bt15"));
    bt15.setTextOn("15 \n" + retornadado("bt15"));


}


public void nextdado() {
    try{
        cursor.moveToNext();

    }
    catch(Exception erro){
        Exibirmensagem("ERRO!","Erro ao avançar com o " +
                "crusor:  "+ erro.getMessage() , "OK");

    }

}


private void iniciaobjetos() {
    try{
        bt01 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt1);
        bt02 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt2);
        bt03 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt3);
        bt04 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt4);
        bt05 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt5);
        bt06 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt6);
        bt07 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt7);
        bt08 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt8);
        bt09 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt9);
        bt10 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt10);
        bt11 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt11);
        bt12 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt12);
        bt13 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt13);
        bt14 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt14);
        bt15 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btt15);
        btnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btNext);
        btprevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtPrevious);
        pageview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        btdescricao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btdescricao);
        botaopage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        etpage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etpage);

    }
    catch(Exception erro){
        Exibirmensagem("ERRO", "erro ao iniciar objetos" +erro.getMessage(),"OK");
    }

}


public void abrebanco(){
    try{
        Banco = openOrCreateDatabase("banco", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pages (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
                ", bt TEXT,bt01 TEXT, bt02 TEXT, bt03 TEXT, bt04 TEXT, bt05 TEXT, bt06 TEXT, " +
                "bt07 TEXT, bt08 TEXT, bt09 TEXT, bt10 TEXT, bt11 TEXT, bt12 TEXT, " +
                "bt13 TEXT, bt14 TEXT, bt15 TEXT)";
        Banco.execSQL(sql);

    }
    catch(Exception erro){
        Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao criar banco: =/"+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
    }
}
public void fechabanco(){
    try{
        Banco.close();          
    }
    catch(Exception erro){
        Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao fechar banco: "+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
    }
}

public boolean buscardados(){
    try{
        cursor = Banco.query("pages",
                new String [] {"bt","bt01","bt02","bt03","bt04","bt05",
                "bt06","bt07","bt08","bt09","bt10",
                "bt11","bt12","bt13","bt14","bt15"}
        , null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception erro){
        Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao buscar no banco: "+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
        return false;
    }
}





public String retornadado(String x){
    String dado = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(x));
    return dado;
}


public void Exibirmensagem (String titulo, 
        String texto, String button)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    mensagem.setTitle(titulo);
    mensagem.setMessage(texto);
    mensagem.setNeutralButton(button,null);
    mensagem.show();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menueditar) {
        Intent iedicao = new Intent(MainActivity.this, paginadeedicao.class);


        iedicao.putExtra("pagina", page);
        startActivity(iedicao);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, edicao.class));
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.menusair) {
        AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = 
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        mensagem.setTitle("Atenção?");
        mensagem.setMessage("Deseja realmente sair?");

        mensagem.setPositiveButton("Sim",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();

            }});
        mensagem.setNegativeButton("Não",null);
        mensagem.show();
        return true;

    }
    if (id == R.id.menusobre) {
        Exibirmensagem("Playback View", "   Esse aplicativo foi desenvolvido com " +
                "objetivo de criar um roller digital e ecologicamente correto, para os " +
                "iluminadores utilizarem como guia dos seus playbacks. \n"+
                "   Todo o copyright ou direitos de propriedade intelectual " +
                "presente em Textos, Imagens, Sons, Softwares e outros conteúdos " +
                "do aplicativo, são de propriedade de Star Lighting Division! \n"+
                "   Em caso de sugestões, " +
                "dúvidas e outros, entre em contato conosco: " +
                "\n(19) 3838-8320 ou vendas@star.ind.br.", "OK");
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.menusite) {
        Uri uriPaginaWeb = Uri.parse("http://star.ind.br/");
        Intent IPaginaWeb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uriPaginaWeb);
        startActivity(IPaginaWeb);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("main", "Executou o onStart();");
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("main", "Executou o onResume();");
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("main", "Executou o onPause();");
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i("main", "Executou o onStop();");
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //banco.close();
    Log.i("main", "Executou o onDestry();");
}
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tv2);

    button.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    p.x = location[0];
    p.y = location[1];
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
    int popupWidth = 300;
    int popupHeight = 400;
    Boolean x=false;
    etpage2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.buttonir);
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, viewGroup);
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
    popup.setContentView(layout);
    popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
    popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
    popup.setFocusable(true);

    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popup.showAtLocation(layout, 
            Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 1, 1 );
    Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonir);
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popup.dismiss();
            valor = etpage.getText().toString();

        }



    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método [`getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29) retorna um **Editable** e não existe qualquer parâmetro equivalente para `String.valueOf()`.

Para obter a string do **EditText**, faça assim:

```
valor = etpage.getText().toString()
```

Comment: Boa tarde, vlw pela dica, mas não funcionou. =/,

Comment: Pode informar o erro que estava acontecendo ou que estava exibindo no console?

Comment: coloquei na pergunta. vlw

Comment: console n aparece nada, e na app ela só para de responder

Comment: Bom, se é *NullPointerException* é porque está tentando acessar algo que não foi instanciado, portanto está nulo. A única possibilidade nesta linha é o próprio campo pela variável `etpage`. Isso foi feito em algum trecho do código antes do click?

Comment: desculpa a ignorância, estanciar é quando vc faz o etpage = (EditText) findbyviewid(r.id.botao)?

Comment: se sim, fiz em escopo global. vou colocar o código todo

Comment: estava olhando a parte de debug, ele não esta conseguindo pegar o conteudo do edit text

Comment: Então é porque a instância está nula. A última dica é conferir se no seu layout, realmente existe um `EditText` com o id `@+id/etpage`.

Comment: mas tem =/
esta muito estranho isso =/ vou refazer, quem sabe da certo